# Too much recursion with GMaps4Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, gmaps4rails

I'm having a problem what I'm not able to fix right now..

Here is my code:
https://gist.github.com/foncho/0bd5d879221c85774346

The problem I have is too much recursion when trying to render all markers

> **x** too much recursion
>
> > ...ction V(){}K=V[H];K.get=function(a){var b=hf(this);a=a+"";b=qe(b,a);if(be(b)){if...
> >
> > > {main,g...try}.js (line 21, col 830)
>
> **x** too much recursion
>
> > function qe(a,b){if(aa[H][ec]Zc)return a[b]};function P(a,b,c){a-=0;b-=0;...
> >
> > > {main,g...try}.js (line 13, col 20)
>
> **x** too much recursion
>
> > ....toUpperCase()+aVb)}function hf(a){a.gm_accessors_||(a.gm_accessors_={});re...
> >
> > > {main,g...try}.js (line 22, col 382)

Any ideas? Any help is welcome!

Thanks in advance

Comment: whats the generated html?

Comment: try to render the map with properly dimensions, but the content was in gray... the objects are generated properly, but not render the markers neither the map... just I've said, container in gray, only with zoom controls...

Comment: this is the HTML I'm getting:

Comment: put the html in your gist

Comment: could you put the resulting html in the gist?